# zeroc define a sequence of self type

Tags: ice

I want to define a class like following with zeroc ICE;

```
class A {
  string someValue;
  sequence<A> children;
};
```

but it seems not work, failed: syntax error;

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
class A;
sequence<A> ASequence;
class A
{
    string someValue;
    ASequence children;
};
```